# windows authentication with NTLM is not working in Safari browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, authentication, safari

I have enabled windows authentication with NTLM provider for my ASP.NET MVC 3.0 application. The application is working fine on IE and Firefox browsers, but it does not work on Safari browser.

Is there any fix to make the application to work in Safari without prompting for username and password window?

Thanks